# Jquery Cookie onclick function

Tags: jquery, function, cookies, onclick

I have this function in jQuery for hide elements when the user click in them:

```
  $(".colabs-image").click(function() {
    $( this ).parent().addClass('is-visited');
  });
```

I want to use a cookie to store the elements in which the user has clicked and display as visited next time.

Whit `$(this).parent().attr('href'))` I have a ID for the element, but I know how to manage the cookie for this task.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at the [jQuery Cookie](http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/) plugin. It makes working with cookies very simple.

Creating the cookie is as simple as:

```
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value');
```

If you want to store the elements in the cookie, it will require a little more work. If your element's id's are static, then you can store them in an array and then store that to the cookie by using `JSON.stringify`:

```
var elements = [];
$(".colabs-image").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().addClass('is-visited');
    elements.push($(this).parent().attr('id')); //add the id to the array of elements
    $.cookie('elements', JSON.stringify(elements));
});
```

To retrieve the elements, you will have to use `JSON.parse`:

```
var elements = JSON.parse($.cookie('elements'));
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    $("#" + elements[i]).addClass('is-visited');
}
```

Comment: Very thanks for your code, is very useful. Btw, I'm newbie in jQuery and I'm doing something wrong. this is my code: http://pastebin.com/f3F0mrKP The console output is: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input  (anonymous function)" If I could explain why I'm so stupid I'd appreciate it.

Comment: @KikoBeats You're welcome! Can you put your code into a fiddle on [jsfiddle.com](http://jsfiddle.com)? It would be easier to see what's happening then.

Comment: nice idea! This is my code without cookie in js file: http://jsfiddle.net/Kikobeats/xNUCF/11/.

Comment: OK, mi problem is with 'elements = JSON.parse($.cookie('elements'));' return undefinied. How I can fix it?